# When accessing a video via the direct file path, what causes it to play in the browser vs open the download dialogue window?

Tags: video

```
This is the desired behavior: https://4rsmokehouse.com/wp-content/themes/4rivers/library/videos/home-loop.mp4
```

Uploading the same video to my test server I get a download prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser will try to play it if you explicitly tell it that the file downloaded is a video file. As @TLJ said you have to pass the

```
Content-Type:video/mp4
or
Content-Type:video/*
```

The response headers returned by your video server link are following

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Sat, 21 Nov 2015 14:49:03 GMT
ETag:"64cdc6-5245826931b62"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

You will need to include the Content-Type header as well to indicate that the file stream is actually a video otherwise browser will assume it's Content-Type is application/octet-stream, which means it has to download the file.

*Edited to add

If you're using Apache to serve the video file, following should be added to **httpd.conf** (Apache configuration file) file or to a **.htaccess** file in the directory where your files are present

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

In your case only video/mp4 will be needed.

Comment: what about if I just enter the direct file path? Is there something I need to configure on the server or within the file?

Comment: The header would have to be configured on the application server that you're uploading the file too, for example if it's Apache server it would have to be done at Apache level.

Comment: I added more information if you're using Apache, if not then add the server information in the question. Then someone may be able to help with the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested out and find that You need 2 headers to do this

1. "Accept-Ranges:bytes"
2. "Content-Type:video/mp4"

Sample code in node.js

```js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("home-loop.mp4");

    res.setHeader("Accept-Ranges","bytes"); //must have
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","video/mp4"); //must have
    //res.setHeader("Content-Range","bytes 0-6606277/6606278")
    //res.setHeader("Content-Length","6606278");
    fileStream.pipe(res);
    return;
}).listen(3000);
```